# VSCode WSL terminal input shows like insert mode when I press KeyUP for the first time

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

[image]

steps:

1. open WSL terminal in VSCODE
2. type anything and the input is fine.
3. press the "UPKEY" for the first time and the input shows like if I pressed insert.
4. I'm saying shows because when I press KEYUP after entering the input the input is correct.
5. You can watch to GIF to understand it.

Pressing the "insert" key doesn't have any effect.

Powershell works fine.

WSL terminal works fine outside VSCODE

[image: extensions]

Comment: Do you have any other terminal extension like Vim installed in VSCode ? If yes, could you try uninstalling it?

Comment: I added an image with all the extensions, I don't see anything that should mess with the terminal

Comment: Ok, nvm I disabled the extensions one by one and it seems to be EditorConfig for some reason

Comment: Glad it worked. Just an fyi : you could run `code --list-extensions` to get list of installed extensions, so you don't have to take screenshots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EditorConfig was messing with my terminal for some reason, disabling it fixes the problem